# Creating table inside teradata procedure gives SELECT error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

I am creating a volatile table in TeraData Studio, inside a `procedure`. I get an error:

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5315 : HY000] SP_EMPLOYEE:An owner referenced by user 
does not have SELECT access to DB_EMP.all_emp.code. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.109
```

I know it has something to do with [`GRANT`](https://forgetcode.com/teradata/1505-error-3523-user-does-not-have-select-grant-option-on-the-table) Option, but I am not able to apply it properly. Here is a small snippet of code:

```
replace PROCEDURE DBX_HOME.SP_Employee(IN variable INTEGER)
begin

   CREATE VOLATILE TABLE TEST_TABLE AS(
   SELECT distinct ID
   FROM DB_EMP.all_emp as prod left join DB_EMP_DWH.ID_no as infra
   ON prod.code=infra.code_infra
   WHERE AND ID MOD 3  = :variable )WITH DATA  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

end;
-- Run the code below.
CALL DBX_HOME.SP_Employee(0)
```

I followed this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/sql-server-create-table-within-stored-procedure), but I am unable to apply `GRANT OPTION` properly. Can anyone suggest where to grant permissions, to avoid this error?

Comment: Depending on your needs you might try different `SQL SECURITY` settings: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/scPHvjfglIlB8F70YliLAw/iLmxPssJoE2qMMnwBfZQtQ  Probably CREATOR or INVOKER

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Where do I need to apply the setting, inside the procedure?

Comment: It's part of the CREATE: `replace PROCEDURE DBX_HOME.SP_Employee(IN variable INTEGER) SQL SECURITY CREATOR begin`

Comment: Regarding GRANT it would be a `grant select on DB_EMP.all_emp to DB_where_SP_is_created WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: Sir, I am a beginner on TeraData and have no undersdtanding of `Grant`. I don't know what magic you have done, but it has solved the problem. I don't get any errors any more. I just added `SQL SECURITY CREATOR` and it worked. Could you kindly add this in answer, so that I can accept?

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer and for your timely help. Grüße

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error pops up when the owner (= database where it's stored) of an object is different from the creator. The general fix in Teradata is to `GRANT SELECT ON db2 to db1 WITH GRANT OPTION` on a database level, which is safe as long as `db1` is a database and not a user.

For Stored procedures there's an alternative, the [SQL SECURITY](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/scPHvjfglIlB8F70YliLAw/iLmxPssJoE2qMMnwBfZQtQ) option from Standard SQL.

Depending on who is supposed to be able to run the SP you might use `SQL SECURITY CREATOR` which checks the rights of the Creator (=user who runs the CREATE PROC) for the SQL submitted within the SP. Or `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` which checks the rights of the CALLing user.

For *Dynamic* SQL the rules are quite complex, above links has all the details.